# How to propagate error in future to parent actor

Tags: scala, akka

I try understand failure handling with `akka` and `futures`.
For example I have parent and child actors.

Child actor have two failure cases:
**case 1)** error happens while message processing
**case 2)** error happens inside future

I need propagate error to parent in both cases, but in second case it's not happens. What's i am doing wrong?

```
import akka.actor.SupervisorStrategy.{Decider, Stop}
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorRef, ActorSystem, OneForOneStrategy, Props, SupervisorStrategy}
import akka.testkit.{TestKit, TestProbe}
import org.junit.{After, Before, Test}

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}


class Parent(_case: String, probe: ActorRef) extends Actor {

  val child = context.actorOf(Props(new Child(_case)), "myLittleChild")

  final val defaultStrategy: SupervisorStrategy = {
    def defaultDecider: Decider = {
      case ex: Exception =>
        probe ! ex
        Stop
    }

    OneForOneStrategy()(defaultDecider)
  }

  override def supervisorStrategy: SupervisorStrategy = defaultStrategy

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case msg => unhandled(msg)
  }

}

class Child(_case: String) extends Actor {

  implicit val ec = context.dispatcher

  override def preStart(): Unit = {
    self ! _case
  }


  override def receive: Receive = {
    case "case1" => throw new RuntimeException("fail")
    case "case2" => Future[String] {
      throw new RuntimeException("fail")
    }.onComplete {
      case Success(s) => println(s)
      case Failure(e) =>
        throw e
    }
    case msg => unhandled(msg)
  }
}


class TestExample {

  protected implicit var system: ActorSystem = _

  @Before
  def setup(): Unit = {
    system = ActorSystem.create("test")
  }

  @After
  def tearDown(): Unit = {
    TestKit.shutdownActorSystem(system)
  }

  @Test
  def case1(): Unit = {
    val testProbe = TestProbe()
    system.actorOf(Props(new Parent("case1", testProbe.ref)))
    testProbe expectMsgClass classOf[RuntimeException]
  }

  @Test
  def case2(): Unit = {
    val testProbe = TestProbe()
    system.actorOf(Props(new Parent("case2", testProbe.ref)))
    testProbe expectMsgClass classOf[RuntimeException]
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your test to pass, you could send the exception to the actor and rethrow the exception from outside the `onComplete` callback:

```
override def receive: Receive = {
  case "case1" => throw new RuntimeException("fail")
  case "case2" =>
    Future[String] {
      throw new RuntimeException("fail")
    }.onComplete {
      case Success(s) => println(s)
      case Failure(e) =>
        self ! e
    }
  case e: RuntimeException => throw e
  case msg => unhandled(msg)
}
```

However, if you must use a `Future` in an actor (e.g., a third-party library whose methods return a `Future`), then there are better ways to handle exceptions. For example, with the database API you mentioned in a comment (`databaseApi.load(): Future[Rows]`), the parent actor could send a `LoadDb` message to the child, and the child could send `Rows` or an error message back to the parent. The child's behavior would look like the following:

```
def receive = {
  case LoadDb =>
    val s = sender // capture the sender
    databaseApi
      .load
      .onComplete {
        case Success(rows) =>
          s ! rows
        case Failure(e) =>
          s ! DbFailure(e)
      }
  case ...
}
```

An important note is that we make a local copy of the `sender` reference when the child receives a `LoadDb` message in order to have a reference to the correct sender from inside the `onComplete` callback. If we just called `sender` inside the callback, this could give erroneous results because `sender` could have changed by the time the callback is executed, as explained [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.3/scala/additional/faq.html?sender-getsender-disappears-when-i-use-future-in-my-actor-why#sender-getsender-disappears-when-i-use-future-in-my-actor-why-). (Unlike `sender`, `self` is immutable, so it's safe to use `self` inside `onComplete`.)

Comment: @zella: Updated.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the way of communicating between parent and child.
The proper way is to define a message containing the failure (and not send an Exception!).
Then the parent can handle the message appropriately.

Also, constructing the child actor you do in the parent is not preferred because this makes it very hard to test the actors. Instead, a child-actor-factory function should be passed into the parent actor as an argument. This can then easily be replaced by a dummy actor (e.g. a TestActorRef or TestProbe) when testing the Parent actor. Similarly the child actor can be tested in isolation to return the proper messages to the parent.

Also, the usage of 'Future' in an actor is not recommended. The actor is already running asynchronous, handling just 1 message at the time. When you  start using Future's in actor, you must handle the case of receiving other messages while the Future has not been completed yet, because the actor could be in an incorrect state until the Future has been completed. A way to get around using Future's in an actor, could be to use a temporary actor as described in the [book 'Effective Akka'](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028789.do) (Extra Pattern, Cameo Pattern).

The ['Effective Akka' book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028789.do) is a good read when starting with Akka. It contains some best practices and things to avoid. It's a small book so quick to read.

**update based on comment:**
In that case you have 2 options:

- since an actor is already running async you could decide to make it synchronous in the actor. That would make it much simpler, but would require blocking.
- Other solution is to handle the onComplete of the Future and send either success or failure message to the parent (or the actor interested in the result). Personally I would not throw exceptions.

  I would pass a child-actor-factory in the parent actor and for the child (or worker) actor either pass in the actor which wants the response or take it from the 'sender'.

  Note that you must capture the 'sender' before calling the Future. And, use a different thread pool otherwise the Future's will use the same thread pool as the actors themselves. And to reuse this pool, this is also something you'd want to pass to the child actor and then you can also adjust it for testing.

I do not understand why you would want to restart the actor. It seems this would be a stateless actor anyway, just an adapter towards the databaseApi.

For implementation of the child actor, you could consider to use the extra/cameo pattern. Then you're sure it receives no other messages (don't forget the stop the actor when it's done). But by making it a separate actor you could, eventually, decide to create a pool of these actors (using a router) to get grip on the number of concurrent db actions.

Comment: Thanks for explanations. And what's about If I already have an api with futures, for example `databaseApi.load():Future[Rows]` and `ChildDatabaseActor` that use it. On some db failure I want restart actor - thats similar in my example code.